# Watir web scraper sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, watir

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
url_input = "www.url.com"
b.goto url_input
b.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 100

h3s = b.h3s class:"class-name"

for h3 in h3s
    h3.wait_until_present

    as = h3.as

    for a in as
        # puts a.text
        name = h3.text
        puts name
    end
end
```

The code sometimes prints the expected name for all of the h3 tags, but sometimes it when I run the program from Terminal, it just doesn't print anything and eventually has an error that begins like this:

> "/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)".

It never works when I try to also print a.text or when I try to get the url of the a tag by doing `url = a.attribute_value('href')` and print that.  It seems odd to me that it sometimes runs and sometimes doesn't.  I suspect it has something to do with the timing, but I don't understand how Watir's timing works at all.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that it was a timing issue.  Eventually I got it to work through:

```
for a in as
    a.wait_until_present
    if a.when_present
        name = a.text
        url = a.attribute_value('href')
    end
end
```

This sometimes worked and sometimes didn't.  It stopped a few times in the middle of parsing my data at random locations.  Sigh, I eventually got the data I needed though.